# THREE.js OrbitControls not working

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, rotation, orbit.js

I'm pretty sure I have everything needed in my JavaScript code for using Three.js OrbitControls. I have:

```
<script>"OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

And also:

```
var cameraControls;
cameraControls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Which it doesn't complain about. But my error says...

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'LEFT' of undefined (21:20:28:855 | error, javascript) at public_html/OrbitControls.js:76

Which refers to the OrbitControls document where it says:

```
this.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT };
```

I don't know how to fix it, anything would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Where does `THREE.MOUSE` get defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ryanpcmcquen suggests already in his comment you are missing `THREE.MOUSE` object. You should load the `three.js` library too to make this work.

The `THREE.MOUSE` object [is defined here in the core of the three.js library](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/Three.js#L114).

```
THREE.MOUSE = { LEFT: 0, MIDDLE: 1, RIGHT: 2 };
```

---

### UPDATE

Make sure you have a `build` version of library loaded where the `THREE.MOUSE` object is defined in the code. I would suggest downloading it from the http://threejs.org/ website.

- here: http://threejs.org/build/three.js for the full version or
- here: http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js for the minified version.

Both those files have the `THREE.MOUSE` object.

---

**Note:** Also think about the correct loading order of your libraries.
You will have to include the `three.js` script **before** your `OrbitControls.js` script.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I actually do have three.js library in my project already but I can't actually find THREE.MOUSE in it for some reason, so I guess I'll have to add it myself...

Comment: @sheavictoria Where did you download your `three.js` library?  I would suggest downloading it from the [http://threejs.org/](http://threejs.org/) website. [here](http://threejs.org/build/three.js) for the full version or [here](http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js) for the minified version. Both those files have a `MOUSE` object.

Comment: @sheavictoria Think also about the loading order of your scripts. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I see that I indeed had revision 58, and not the current, which was the problem, now it's working!! Thanks so much!